# Recording Sound Through Casio Keyboard Using Audacity

Tags: keyboard, sound, homerecording, audacity

My Casio WK-110 has four ports... a USB port (used for MIDI recording), a sustain port (used for sustain pedals), a power port, and a phones/output jack. I would like to record the SOUND of my keyboard using Audacity on my Windows laptop. However, when I use a wire to connect the phones port to the headphones/mic port on my laptop, I notice two things:

1. Playing the keyboard results in no sound from the keyboard's speakers (as expected).
2. When I hit record on Audacity, it records through the microphone of my computer... I've tried messing around with the settings on Audacity, but with no luck.

It seems as if the laptop doesn't recognize that the keyboard is connected to it.

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your laptop has a shared headphone/microphone port, it will often ask you to tell it what kind of device you plugged in when it detects you've done so. If it's not doing that, it might be sticking with the default setting (probably headphones) and not 'switching on' on the microphone functionality of the port. There might be a way to override the setting in your laptop's sound properties program. This varies by laptop so you'd need to consult the laptop's operating manual (if you don't have it, they can usually be found online by searching for the laptop model number).

Answer (score 1):

When I've encountered this before, I needed to select the correct recording device. It's the second drop down in this toolbar:

[image]

The full manual page is worth a read: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_selecting_your_recording_device.html

This question may also be of interest, if there is no recording device present in the dropdown:
[Connecting a Keyboard to Record in Audacity](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45946/connecting-a-keyboard-to-record-in-audacity)